# LaTeX Tikz - "did you forget a semicolon" with this flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, pdftex, nodes

I cannot get this document to render.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex]
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm, minimum height=2em]

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} [h] % here
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 4cm, auto]
% % Place nodes
\node [block] (start) {Lorem};
\node [decision, below of=start] (decide) {Ipsum};
\node [block, left of=decide] (dagens) {Lorem};
\node [block, below of=dagens] (spara) {Ipsum};
\node [block, right of=decide] (ladda) {Lorem};
\node [block, below of=decide] (satt) {Ipsum};
\node [cloud, below of=satt] (resten) {Lorem Ipsum};

\draw [line] (start) -- (decide); % if i remove this line it works
\draw [line] (decide) -- (dagens);
\draw [line] (dagens) -- (spara);
\draw [line] (spara) -- (satt);
\draw [line] (satt) -- (resten);
\draw [line] (decide) -- (ladda);
\draw [line] (ladda) -- (satt);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption {Lorem Ipsum} 
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I always get this error:

```
! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.26 \draw [line]
                   (start) -- (decide);
?
```

Im running OSX, using pdflatex from the Terminal to render.

Comment: I can’t reproduce on OS X (Yosemite, MacTeX). Have you tried deleting your auxiliary files (.aux, .log, etc) and recompiling?

Comment: @alexwlchan Tried it, didnt work

Comment: Here is entire Terminal output: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/HAMmWGgj)

Comment: Maybe you have some non-printable character in your `.tex` file that upsets the parser. Could you try deleting the offending line and retyping it (not copy-pasting it)?

Comment: @Jake fascinating, very fascinating. I get a new error, even though its the exact same line.
    ! Package PGF Math Error: You asked me to calculate `1/0.0', but I cannot divid
e any number by zero.

Comment: @qwerty1911: Strange. Maybe you could copy the code from the question and paste it into a new document and try to compile that?

Comment: @Jake i'm speechless. it worked.

Comment: @qwerty1911: Hm, so it seems like there was something off with the original file. I guess this question can be closed then?

Comment: @Jake yes. im trying to think how though as the answer was provided by you in the comments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was likely caused by an invisible character, and fixed by copying the code back into the editor from TeX.SX.